# Is it possible to extend DefaultValueAccessor?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am wondering if I have to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` to get the same behavior as with the `DefaultValueAccessor` for my own component or can I extend the class?

Extending the class ends with a template parse error (yes, the component is already part of the module).

module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent ,
        DatePickerComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

component:

```
export class DatePickerComponent extends DefaultValueAccessor {
```

error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'date-picker' is not a known element:
1. If 'date-picker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'date-picker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="input-group">
            [ERROR ->]<date-picker [name]="beginn" [(ngModel)]="startDate"></date-picker>
        </div>
        <p id="b"):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some newer angular version it is possible to extend the [DefaultValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5efc86069ff92d980bb460c15deccb1e0fff9363/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L59) and register the value accessor without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include 'date-picker' into directives array of your module?

Comment: Added to my question.

Comment: I've found post about creating custom controls http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14080433)

Comment: @trungk18 I ment that maybe author of the question missed something, and in this post is described by steps how to implement the ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Yeah, but you can also comment when you have enough reputation (>50). Just a remark, no worries :)

Comment: @trungk18 Yeah, i tried to comment, but the only way to communicate  was to post an answer.

Comment: So try to provide the full answer, then user can vote for you. After gain enough reputation you can comment to every question.

Comment: @trungk18 Thank you for advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126599/discussion-between-trungk18-and-zasypin-n-v).